# Babel Unexpected toek import using "modules": false option with es2015

Tags: javascript, babeljs, webpack-2

I'm building an app using [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader)

As I'm using Webpack 2, I need to disable the module options for es2015, and my .babelrc looks like:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
    "react", 
    "stage-0"
  ],

  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    "add-module-exports",
    "transform-react-display-name",
    "flow-runtime",
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

My webpack dev.config.js file:

```
require('babel-polyfill');

// Webpack config for development
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var assetsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../static/dist');
var host = (process.env.HOST || 'localhost');
var port = (+process.env.PORT + 1) || 3001;

// https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools
var WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin = require('webpack-isomorphic-tools/plugin');
var webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin = new WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin(require('./webpack-isomorphic-tools'));

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
  entry: {
    'main': [
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://' + host + ':' + port + '/__webpack_hmr',
      './src/client.js'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: assetsPath,
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: 'http://' + host + ':' + port + '/dist/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']},
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
      { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style-loader!css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!less?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap' },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style-loader!css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap' },
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
      { test: webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.regular_expression('images'), loader: 'url-loader?limit=10240' }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'src',
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['*', '.json', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    // hot reload
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/webpack-stats\.json$/),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __CLIENT__: true,
      __SERVER__: false,
      __DEVELOPMENT__: true,
      __DEVTOOLS__: true  // <-------- DISABLE redux-devtools HERE
    }),
    webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.development()
  ]
};
```

When running babel is showing the following error:

```
 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Express from 'express';
[1]                                                               ^^^^^^
[1] SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
[1]     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
[1]     at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
[1]     at loader (D:\9. DEV\WORKSPACE\noname\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
[1]     at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\9. DEV\WORKSPACE\noname\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
[1]     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
[1]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
[1]     at Module._load (module.js:438:3)
[1]     at Function.module._load (D:\9. DEV\WORKSPACE\noname\node_modules\piping\lib\piping.js:218:16)
[1]     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
[1]     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
[0] Hash: 5c8e594486d73f27c13f
[0] Version: webpack 2.3.1
[0] Time: 3340ms
```

Reading [this tutorial](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hmr-react/#app-code) seens that there is a problem with node:

> Note: Node.js doesn't support ES2015 modules yet and using ES2015
>   modules in your webpack 2 configuration file will cause an issue.
>
> To work around this you will need two .babelrc file to transpile the
>   configuration and app code separately:
>
> in the project root directory with "presets": ["es2015"] in the source
>   directory for app code

Do I really need to build 2 `.babelrc` files ? Is there an updated working solution for this ?

Comment: This comment just says that you can't use Es2015 import in your webpack.config.js as it will be directly read by node and not transpiled. What kind of imports are you using in your webpack config?

Comment: Added webpack configuration to the original post.

Comment: It seems to work without any problem for me. Could you try a minimal application and minimal webpack config just to deal with this problem? Maybe something else is causing the problem